# Convert Oracle collection type to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm working on a database migration (Oracle to SQL Server) using the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle tool by microsoft.

However I get the following error message while performing the db conversion:

```
-02SS0472: Conversion of 'MY_CUSTOM_TYPE' failed because collection type is not supported;
```

MY_CUSTOM_TYPE is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "MY_CUSTOM_TYPE" is table of number(8);
```

I would like to know how I can get an SQL Server equivalent of that and solve my issue.

Comment: If you are using this for a nested table, you will probably need to change the data model or use XML.

Answer (score 1):

The normal SQL parallel of a collection would simply be to add another table, with a foreign key back to this table and put all the values from the collection in there... As Gordon suggested you could also use an XML or JSON column type, but this adds complexity when querying the data

Edit:

Say your first table was like;

Table1

Id, SomeOtherColumns, CollectionColumn

You should now make

Table1

Id, SomeOtherColumns

Table2

Id, Table1Id, CollectionContent

and you would put **each** element of the collection into Table2, with the Table1Id corresponding to the row in Table1 it came from... does that make sense?

So you would have the same number of rows in table 1, but for each item of each collection in table1, you will have a row in table 2

Comment: Could you please give more details, where should I add the foreing key you are talking about? @Milney

Comment: @Neo see edit, can add more detail later but rushing now, hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Yeah I think I get it, in your example 'CollectionColumn' in Table1 is a column of type 'MY_CUSTOM_TYPE' right?

Comment: It would be one of the mssql numeric types (int for integers or Decimal for real numbers), and you would have for example, 8 rows with the same Table1Id (1 row for each of the 8 elements of the collection). As in MSSQL you cannot have types which consist of more than 1 element, so you need to 'expand' the 8 values into 8 rows

Comment: Yes I understand this principle I just wanted to confirm that in Table1 in your example, the colum CollectionColumn is originally of type 'MY_CUSTOM_TYPE' in Oracle